# Adding image to header - is #{request.contextPath} returning contextname/faces instead of just contextname/?

Tags: css, primefaces, styles

I am attempting to add an image to the header of my layoutUnits (specifically layoutUnit = North but I can work it out). However, while it works for pages before login, it stops working after I login. I was wondering if the reason for that was because #{request.contextPath} returns

```
https://localhost:8181/contextname/faces
```

instead of just:

```
https://localhost:8181/contextname/
```

or is there some other cause? The more I think about it, the more I think it is probably something else - but I can't think what. Note that the style sheet below works for 8080 and 8181 - that's not causing the issue that I can tell.

Here is the CSS I modified - like I said, it works outside of login, but once logged in the image fails to appear.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-layout-unit-header{
            background-image:url('#{request.contextPath}images/NetworksLogoToolbarTransparent.gif') !important;
            background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
            background-size: contain !important;
        }
    </style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Aodhán

Answer (score 0):

I have literally no idea why, so if anyone could shed light on it, that'd be great, but for some reason adding a / before images worked. It wasn't necessary before logging in, but was for logged in pages. So:

```
background-image:url('#{request.contextPath}/images/NetworksLogoToolbarTransparent.gif') !important;
```

Instead of:

```
background-image:url('#{request.contextPath}images/NetworksLogoToolbarTransparent.gif') !important;
```

The examples I saw didn't need the slash, but mine did.